# How to do some visible actions during telephone call?

Tags: android

Is it possible to do some visible actions during telephone call?

It could be something like:

- play custom animation
- inject some custom layout with controls

Comment: How is anyone going to see your visible actions with their ear stuck to the device?

Comment: they are expected to be visible until you press ANSWER CALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to do something when Intent.ACTION_ANSWER is dispatched?

One idea - override the native Phone application (use appropriate Intent Filter, take a look [here](http://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=kippee&logNo=130045027439) to see how Android resolves best matching Intent Filters), display your layout (including Answer/Reject buttons) and then use something like

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
startNextMatchingActivity(intent);
```

to start the Phone application.

I can see some problems with that solution - UI inconsistency and problems with programmaticaly answering the call (non-trivial, but not impossible), but it should be easy to try.

What are you trying to do?

If you want to mess with the layout when answering a call, your application has to be pretty close/duplicating the Phone app. It seems that's not the case, otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Thanks. Does that also mean that I can even possibly create my own Phone application and somehow bind it to launch during INCOMING CALL event?

Comment: Yes, you can write your own Phone application, you can extend the default one, you can pretty much change everything - the built-in apps don't have higher priority than third party apps.

Comment: Could you please share some links where you take all this interesting information :) ?